# Magento : WYSIWYG in custom widget

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, ce-1.9.1.0, widgets, wysiwyg

I have tried adding a WYSIWYG editor to custom widget I have created using the approach outlined at: http://behrendtio.github.io/2013/04/12/using-a-wysiwyg-editor-in-a-magento-widget/

However, when I insert the widget on a CMS page and I try to save the page i get the following error in a JS alert:

```
error: error in [unknown.object].fireEvent();

event name: formSubmit()

error message: Cannot set property 'value' of null
```

I have been able to determine that if I add more WYSIWYG editors into the widget, I get more popups.

It does actually save the content though. I am doing this for a client however, and we do not want our client getting unexplainable errors every time they save a page.

I am not really sure where to go from here. I can't seem to find a reason as to why those 2 are connected and even less how to get rid of the error altogether.